# Paypal Payment Integration with PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I have been searching for Paypal Payment integration code with PHP.

There are too many documents about PayPal Payment API, and I got confused which I have to use.

I hope you can help me what PayPal Code that I can use.

Here is the point for my website payment.

- PHP website
- A user will type amount of fund that they want to put on the website.
- A user clicks submit button and it will redirect to Paypal Page (The user can log in with his or her Paypal account)
- After the user successfully pay the fund through Paypal, it redirects back to website.

If you know a website or article to figure out this process, please put a comment with the address.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use their Adaptive Payments APi.  Their site has all the documentation you should need.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a donation site you can use paypal button factory to get a button and add to your site and done. Else go to this site and select digital goods option. https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ 
This gives you readymade code :)
Best part is payment is made on your site. No redirects :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on my previous answer, the solution is 1.index.php-The payment form, 2.ipn.php-the engine that responds to paypal, sends emails and write to database and 3.reconcile.php-the back end tool that allows the receiver to review transactions

Comment: I think this should have been an update on your previous answer.

Comment: consider editing your existing answer to add the details.

Answer (score -2):

I have been working on a similar proposition. I have created a simple php/html page that takes an amount, an invoice number and some payer details (name,email and phone). This passes to paypal, processes a payment and then returns. Emails are sent to the sender and receiver of the payment and the payee has a "reconciliation" listing of all payments received.
Have a look at ingram.org.au and follow the links to PayMyTradie..
The concept is based on Tradesmen (Electricians, plumbers, etc) who have websites, but, because they dont sell a product, are pretty much excluded from a "shopping cart" payment process.
They are excluded no longer and the concept is taking off!!